# How to conditionally add another filter to a query in Firebase Firestore using swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project using Google firebase firestore.
I wanna implement a filter on my search for users. Imagine the search for only active users with a checkbox which users can select.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let reference = db.collection("users").limit(to: 20)
//FILTER
if showOnlyActiveUsersBtn.isSelected {
    reference.whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)
}
reference.getDocuments(completion: {(querySnapshot, error) in
    .....
})
```

I expected this would return the result with only users who have the field "active: true", however, it returned the same list as the query without the filter...
if I write like:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let reference = db.collection("users").limit(to: 20).whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)
reference.getDocuments(completion: {(querySnapshot, error) in
    .....
})
```

It returns the result I expected first.
I don't have any idea why my filter doesn't work.
How can I add logical "AND" condition with user-friendly way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firestore Query objects are immutable, meaning that they can never be modified after they are created.  In your code, you aren't remembering the new query you built with `whereField`.  Instead, you need to build a new Query object on top of an existing query, and remember the new one:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var reference = db.collection("users").limit(to: 20)
if showOnlyActiveUsersBtn.isSelected {
    // build a new query using the old query, reassign to reference
    reference = reference.whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)
}
reference.getDocuments(completion: {(querySnapshot, error) in
    .....
})
```

If you don't like using `var` instead of `let`, I'm sure you can find a way to rework this sample.  In any event, you will need to remember the new query returned by `whereField`, and use that to call `getDocuments`.

Comment: Doug
Thanks! I didn't know Firestore Query objects are immutable. Your answer will help not only me but also others who don't know that :) Thank you!