# How do I remove the listener for addSnapshotListener used in Firestore pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The Firestore pagination example on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) is as follows:

```swift
let first = db.collection("cities")
    .order(by: "population")
    .limit(to: 25)

first.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        print("Error retrieving cities: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return
    }

    guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
        // The collection is empty.
        return
    }

    // Construct a new query starting after this document,
    // retrieving the next 25 cities.
    let next = db.collection("cities")
        .order(by: "population")
        .start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)

    // Use the query for pagination.
    // ...
}
```

Detaching a listener for the `ListenerRegistration` just requires the `remove` method, according to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

But, `first` in the above example is `Query`, which has the `removeObserver` method that requires an observer object and a key path as the arguments.

**Update**

The reason I need to distinguish the listener from the query reference is because I'm trying to incorporate the ability to 1) detach the listener 2) have an optional `whereField` and 3) paginate. These require 1) `ListenerRegistration` which is `first` in the following example, 2) `Query`, the `ref` variable and 3) `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, the `lastSnapshot` variable, respectively.

```swift
var ref = db.collection("cities")
    .order(by: "population")
    .limit(to: 25)

if let searchTerm = searchTerm {
    ref = ref.whereField("population", isGreaterThan: searchTerm)
}

let first = ref.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
        return
    }
    
    // Use the query for pagination.
    // ...
}
```

So above example is how I interpreted @Frank's comment:

> At some point you'll also need to call `next.addSnapshotListener`, which returns you another ListenerRegistration that you can call `remove()` on when its time

But, `snapshot.documents.last` to capture the `lastSnapshot` is always `nil` in this case.

Comment: Since you already found the relevant documentation on removing a listener, what is keeping you from capturing the return value from `addSnapshotListener` in a variable (say `listener`) and calling `listener.remove()`?

Comment: `first` in the above example doesn't seem to have the `remove()` method, only `removeObserver`.

Comment: You need to store the *return value* from calling `addSnapshotListener` in a variable. See my answer below.

Comment: I don't think the fact that `snapshot.documents.last` is `null` is related to whether/how you're capturing `first` here. If you're having a hard time getting results with this query, I recommend opening a new question for that - showing the exact value you use for `searchTerm`, and a screenshot of the document you expected to be in `snapshot.documents.last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `addSnapshotListener` it returns a function that you can call to remove the listener. So you need to store the return value in a variable, and then call `remove` on it after that.

From the documentation on [detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener):

```
let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    // ...
}

// ...

// Stop listening to changes
listener.remove()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I needed to use the `Query` object, which is what the variable `first` is in my question, not the `listener` variable you specified, which is an `ListenerRegistration` object.  For example, I'm using the `Query` object in the above format to have conditional `whereField` filters, similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130218/10116367.

Comment: The above approach works, is how it is documented, and does not conflict with anything you already had in your code. I'm also not aware of the `removeObserver` you mention in the Firestore API, and can't find it in the documentation either: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query A `removeObserver` *does* exist for Realtime Database, but that's a different set of classes altogether. I'd recommend doing what I have in my answer, and not pursue `removeObserver` further.

Comment: I'm able to use the `remove()` only if I add `addSnapshotListener` as you mentioned in your example `let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener{...}`, but in order for me to use the conditional `whereField`, I would need to have a reference without `addSnapshotListener` like this `var first = db.collection("cities")` so that I could add a conditional `whereField` like this `first.whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)`. But, the problem is the reference `first`, in this case, doesn't have a method like this `first.remove()`.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the problem is. You call `first.addSnapshotListener` already, so can capture the return value from that in a variable (like in my answer/the docs) and call `remove()` on it. At some point you'll also need to call `next.addSnapshotListener`, which returns you another `ListenerRegistration` that you can call `remove()` on when its time.